# How can i know which categories of the text input belongs to?

Tags: java, php, jsp

Currently i have to did it manually flip around the taxonomy book and write down the category.I wish i could create a system that automatically find which categories are my input belongs to and output the name of the category.

Can some1 teach me how or giv me some ideas?

So if i input this "Change the plan" then the output will be "Adaption P6" in "Psychomotor Domain" since the keyword change is under it.
Below is the image of how the keywords are categorized ,its a small book.

Comment: Do u mean the user will enter some data and u need to classify them depending on special criteria u have?

Comment: Yes,Alaa.And output only the category of the data entered

Answer (score 0):

You have basically answered your question yourself: Maintain a list of keywords belonging to the categories you want to assign, search for the keywords in the input text, then assign the categories if the keyword is found.

Depending on the content of the texts, this might prove insufficient, though: Simple keyword searches just don't measure up to a human editor doing classification.  In any case, you should still allow a human reader to verify, and perhaps change, the results.

"Real" semantic searches are one of the most complex concepts in computer science, and I haven't ever heard of a project that successfully implemented one that could outperform a human.

Comment: Hi,thanks for d answer.But they are categorized already in the image.Do not need the semantic searches. can you teach me how shud i create the database with categories ? I have search for tutorials but could not find it ;( and i am only beginner familiar with phpmyadmin .

Comment: Since I don't know anything about your data, where and how your categories are stored, etc. I really can't tell you how to do it.  I don't even know if you are using a third party software or if you have access to the source code at all, or what language it is in.  phpMyAdmin is a nice tool for maintaining MySQL databases, and you could possibly do what you are trying to do just by using MySQL queries - but if you do this often, you really wouldn't want to.  Instead, there should be some kind of web application where you can log in and just start the process by clicking a button.

Comment: Someone must have written the application you work with - can't you talk to them about adding such a feature?

Comment: its an app that i will start from scratch .i wish to use jsp with phpmyadmin and mysql database.but i duno how should i create my database...my data is like this

Comment: EG Input text : "Describe the diagram below"
 (so describe is in Perception P1 Physchomotor Domain)
 the output will be : Perception p1, Physchomotor Domain

Comment: but there are 3 more domains which make it like a hierarchy where the domains are the parents of the p1,p2 and so on...how shud i build my database like this ? different domain hav different numbers of p1,p2

Comment: I think this should be a new question, because it goes into far more detail than what these comments are intended for.  Just make sure you provide all the info from your comments above and make your question text more concrete, like "How do I set up a database application to hierarchically categorize text?".